# problems updating packages in anaconda navigator

Tags: anaconda

I cannot update packages in anaconda navigator.

Procedure: 
1. Update index
2. mark packages, that I want to update
3. click apply

After a while the window remains empty and nothing happens (see figure).

I already deleted anaconda completely from my computer and installed it again. The problem remains.

I tried to update packages from the command line: conda update --all and it seem to work.

But when I checked my anaconda navigator for updatable packages, it shows me

194 updatable packages in the base(root) environment and 40 updatable packages in the anaconda3 environment. By the way...what is the difference between these two environments? Thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need update anaconda-navigator with

```html
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

anaconda docs.
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/update-navigator/

Comment: thanks, but I still got updatable packages in both environments. how would you recommend to update packages on anaconda navigator? do you have to update every package one by one? I couldn't find help for my update problems although there are other users with the same problem...

Comment: Updating anaconda-navigator did not work for me neither. A workaround on short notice may be the package update via cmd, which is working for me at least. I tried to elaborate a bit on the problem in my recent questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334344/anaconda-3-package-version-mismatch-between-command-line-and-navigator-gui-sti

Comment: In my opinion I prefer to work with a previous version to the most recent one, since they tend to be more stable and with fewer errors.
The advantage with this is that the newer versions have better optimization, but it is already a matter of taste and needs.